# can we use input() in subprocess to assign value in parameter

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

```
subprocess.Popen('lccomm','n=RACK')
```

//i want something like this

subprocess.Popen('lccomm','n=input()')

Comment: why not just use string interpolation with `subprocess.Popen('lccomm','n=%s' % input() )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting for Python 3.6, there is a convenient feature called f-string

```
subprocess.Popen('lccomm', f'n={input()}')
```

For Python 3.5-, there are also multiple string formatting options. For example, as mentioned by Ruzihm in his helpful comment

```
subprocess.Popen('lccomm', 'n=%s' % input())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arg = input()

subprocess.Popen('lccomm','n={}'.format(arg))
```